# Locally redefine figure environment as figure* for automated export

Tags: floats, pandoc, grouping, definition, starred-version

I'm using a workflow based on `pandoc` and Latex to produce papers with my companies layout. Part of the formatting are captions set inside the margin and sometimes using images that span text and margin area. Both can easily be achieved with the `sidenotes` package. It enables large figures modifying the `figure*` environment.

In a plain text document switching between regular `figure` and `figure*` is of course no problem. But I have to use an automated workflow with `pandoc` from markdown through Latex to PDF. Unfortunately, `pandoc` offers no built-in option to switch between starred and regular environment. Thus, I've written a Lua filter which wraps figures marked as starred inside a group and in there locally redefines `figure` to act like `figure*`. This is necessary since `pandoc` always outputs regular `figure` commands. Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Here is a MWE with a short Latex example which could be a `pandoc` output:

```latex
% !TeX lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[outer=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begingroup
\RenewEnvironmentCopy{figure}{figure*}
\begin{figure}
\rule{\linewidth}{2ex}
\sidecaption{some text}
\end{figure}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

The log shows the following error message:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=200000].
\tl_set:Nn ..._set:Ne #1{\__kernel_exp_not:w {#2}}
                                                  
l.11 \rule
        {\linewidth}{2ex}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

Enlarging TeX's capacity doesn't solve the problem. The problem also persists if I load `graphicx` and use an image instead of a rule.

I'm hoping for some ideas how to solve this.

Other approaches to locally redefine `figure` as `figure*` are also very welcome. But its obligatory that in the Latex document the environment itself is typed as simple `figure` since this output is kind of hardcoded in `pandoc`.

**Edit**

Thanks to @cabohas solution I got it to work. Here is the Lua filter I use with pandoc like `pandoc -s -L path/to/filter.lua file.md -o file.tex`:

```lua
if FORMAT:match 'latex' then
   function Figure (elem)
      local starred = elem.content[1].content[1].attributes['starred']
      if starred and starred == "true" then
         return {
            pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\defaultwidefiguretrue'),
            elem,
            pandoc.RawInline('latex', '\\defaultwidefigurefalse')
         }
      else
         return elem
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that it is a really good idea of sidenotes to redefine figure* like this. It breaks figure handling in twocolumn mode.

Comment: That should be no problem in my special case since there is no need for two column mode with the used layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that the `sidenote` definition of `figure*` internally uses `figure`. So after redefining `figure*`, the internal usage also uses `figure*`. This results in an infinite loop.

I would recommend to define two new environments `figure-` and `figure+`. `figure-` can be a simple copy of the normal `figure`, but `figure+` has to be a copy of `figure*` with usage of `figure-` instead of `figure`. After this, you can redefine `figure` to either use `figure-` or `figure+`, e.g., depending on a `\if…` switch. Additionally `figure*` should also be changed to be an alias of `figure+`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[outer=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\NewEnvironmentCopy{figure-}{figure}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentEnvironment{figure+}{ O{htbp} }
{
    \begin{figure-}[#1]
        \begin{autoadjustwidth}{}{-\@sidenotes@extrawidth}
        \captionsetup{style=widefigure}
}
{
        \end{autoadjustwidth}
    \end{figure-}
}
\makeatother  
\newif\ifdefaultwidefigure
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{figure}{ O{htbp} }
{
  \ifdefaultwidefigure
    \def\figureenvtype{figure+}%
  \else
    \def\figureenvtype{figure-}%
  \fi
  \begin{\figureenvtype}[#1]%
}
{
  \end{\figureenvtype}
}
\RenewEnvironmentCopy{figure*}{figure+}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\defaultwidefigurefalse% first example not wide
\begin{figure}
\rule{\linewidth}{2ex}
\sidecaption{some text}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\defaultwidefiguretrue% second example wide
\begin{figure}
\rule{\linewidth}{2ex}
\sidecaption{some text}
\end{figure}

\blindtext
\begin{figure*}% third example wide by used environment
\rule{\linewidth}{2ex}
\sidecaption{some text}
\end{figure*}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Of course its the `sidenotes` package. Should've checked it myself... Could another solution be to save `figure` environment to let's say `origfigure` and replace all occurrences of `figure` inside the `figure*` definition of the `sidenotes` package with `origfigure`? I've to try your solution when I'm back from work.

Comment: OK, I commented before reloading the page to see your edit. That looks very good. Will try it out asap.

Comment: Thats the solution I needed. Thanks! Its kind of what I thought of repalcing `figure` inside the `figure*` environment defined by `sidenotes`. I already integrated it into my pandoc workflow (see my edit if interested in such things). In case the workflow gets officially published, I will reference your solution in a proper way.